# Firestore read count spike

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I noticed spikes in my Firestore read count so I added traces when a large number of documents are being read. Today I noticed a jump from 19k read to 38k read (double), in one specific hour.

Looking in my traces, I saw only 4k read. Assuming not everything is recorded, let's more than double it to 10k read. Still, Firestore reported 19k read! I have no idea if it came from my code or something is broken on Firestore side. I saw other posts here with this issue, all left alone with no solution because Firebase has no report to show the collections affected by those reads. How convenient.

Last week my read count were 160k in one day and the next day it was 68k read in 3 hours. VERY strange. That was the reason I added the traces on my side but still it keeps me blind like in the scenario I wrote before.

I'm using admin SDK and set a rule that NO ONE can have access to my database.
Thanks

Comment: Since we don't know how exactly you are using Firestore, it's not possible to know where your reads are coming from.  But it's a common mistake to leave the Firestore console open where it consumes updates from the open collection for as long as the browser window stays open.

Comment: For that reason I made a "special" collection that shows first in the list and it contains only one document. Whenever I go to the data section, that collection is loaded first and consumes only 1-2 reads.